# Does Flux.jl have tensor objects?

Tags: julia, flux.jl

Coming from Tensorflow and Pytorch, does Flux.jl contain a tensor like structure? If not, what is the common way to structure your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Flux.jl docs](https://fluxml.ai/tutorials/2020/09/15/deep-learning-flux.html):

> The starting point for all of our models is the Array (sometimes referred to as a Tensor in other frameworks). This is really just a list of numbers, which might be arranged into a shape like a square.

So given this, the way to represent data is just via traditional matrices (which are just arrays). You can find out more about Julia's first class array support here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/

Comment: To add a bit of background: TF and PyTorch are (to a certain extent) based on an operator-overloading approach to implement AD -- Python is just not as extensible as Julia with its multiple dispatch, and  they almost _have to_ resort to custom tensor "wrapper types". (But have a look at JAX for a different approach). Julia, on the other hand, allows operator overloading to be implemented in a much more hidden fashion; besides that, Zygote uses source transformation, which avoids the tracing part completely.